# Windows needs permission from Unix User\Root to delete/move in a samba share

Tags: 12.04, networking, permissions, samba, file-sharing

so my samba share requires permissions from Unix User\root to move or delete files. I don't understand why. You don't need to login to access the samba share. Just need to be on the network. The share is mounted at `/media/Network` on the server computer.

Here's the error I get when I try deleting/moving a file:
[image: error 1]

smb.conf:

```
[Network]
    path = /media/Network
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    force user = cody
    guest ok = yes
```

Permissions: (ls -la /media/Network) (The red covered things are user folders I created)
[image: permissions]

Comment: What are the permissions, at Linux level of your share (`ls -la /media/Netwok`) ? Is the Linux user *cody* allowed to read and write, at Linux level ?

Comment: Yeah, @Benoit. That user can add folders and delete anything. The share was created under than account.

Comment: @Benoit, see OP. Put the `ls -la /media/Network` output in it.

Comment: *cody* may read under `/media/Netwok` but not write. Did you create this directory using `sudo` maybe ? In this case it is not *cody* who did the action but *root*. This is the purpose of `sudo`

Comment: @Benoit The directory is an external USB hard drive, so I didn't create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions listed here don't allow the user *cody* to write at Linux level but well to read.

So if you force Samba to use this Linux user when accessing the share (`force user = cody`), you won't be able to write either from Windows.

Evreything is owned by *root* from `/media/Network` with write access only allowed to the user owning the directory or the file, in this case *root*.

So what you have to do is to switch the owner of the files and directories starting with and below `/media/Network` to have a write access from Windows.

```
sudo chown -R cody /media/Network
```

When setting up Samba, you don't have to forgot that the read and write access coming from a Windows PC are to be translated by the **smbd** daemon of Samba into Linux read and write, using a valid Linux user and subject to the underlaying Linux filesystem permissions.
In your Samba configuration extract, you tell Samba to use the Linux user *cody* to access the directories and files under `/media/Network`. Forgetting about the Windows username that is passed in the connection between Windows and Samba.

Comment: Got an error. `Function not implemented.` Any idea?

Comment: Figured out that my error was because the drive was formatted to exFAT. Gonna format it and try again.